# Geometry Proof Concerning Equality of Lengths on a Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, quadrilateral

> Quadrilateral $WXYZ$ has right angles at $\angle W$ and $\angle Y$ and an acute angle at $\angle X$. Altitudes are dropped from $X$ and $Z$ to diagonal $\overline{WY}$, meeting $\overline{WY}$ at $O$ and $P$ as shown. Prove that $OW = PY$.

The proof requires the use of similarity and special triangle parts and properties.

[image]

Comment: You should give some sense of your own thinking about the problem, so that we can tailor answers to fit your skill level and/or address particular points of confusion. Be that as it may ... You note that the solution requires similarity. Recall that we can prove two triangles similar by showing that two sets of corresponding angles are congruent; with right triangles, half of that burden is essentially lifted. Here, with the extra right angles at $W$ and $Y$, you'll find that every (acute) angle in the figure has a match, so identifying similar triangles should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use circumcirles. Since $\angle \, XYZ = \angle \, XWZ = 90^{\circ}$ the quad $XYZW$ is inscribed in a circle $k$ and $XZ$ is a diameter whose midpoint $S$ it the center of $k$. Extend $XO$ until it intersect $k$ for the second time at point $U$. Let $\angle \, XYW = \alpha$ and $\angle \, XWY = \beta$. Then $\angle \, XZY = \angle \, WWY = \beta$ so $$\angle \, ZXY = 90^{\circ} - \beta = \angle \, WXO = \angle \, WXU$$ which yields $$YZ = WU$$ Moreover, if $\angle \, UXZ = \theta$ then 
$$\angle \, UWO = \angle \, UWY = \angle\, UXY = \beta + \theta = \angle \, ZXW = \angle \, ZYW = \angle \, ZYP$$ Consequently triangles $UWO$ and $ZYP$ are congruent and hence $OW = PY$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a}{p} = \frac{q}{a+b} \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{c}{q} = \frac{p}{b+c} &\quad\to\quad a(a+b) = pq = c(b+c) \\[4pt]
&\quad\to\quad a(a+b)-c(b+c) = 0 \\[4pt]
&\quad\to\quad (a-c)(a + b + c ) = 0 \\[4pt]
&\quad\to\quad a = c \quad\square
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear that the said quadrilateral is circumscribed by the black circle.

[image]

Construction: 1) Extend XO to cut the circle at Q. 2) Join WQ. 3) Join ZQ. 4) Join XZ.

$\angle 1 = \angle 3$ because they both are equal to $\angle 2$. This means WQ = YZ and arc WQ = arc YZ.

Adding the common arc ZQ to both arcs, we have the green arcs are equal. This means $\angle PYZ = \angle OWQ$.

We now have sufficient info to conclude that $\triangle YPZ \cong \triangle WOQ$. Result follows.